Can $\mathbb{C}$ have a "doppelganger" in $L(\mathbb{R})$ with countable automorphism group?
Working in $\mathsf{ZFC}$ + large cardinals (a proper class of Woodins, to be precise), is there a field $F\in L(\mathbb{R})$ such that $V\models F\cong\mathbb{C}$ and $L(\mathbb{R})\models\vert\mathit{Aut}(F)\vert=\aleph_0$?
Taking $F=\mathbb{C}$ gives an "internal automorphism group" of $\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$. Conversely, we can build inside $L(\mathbb{R})$ an algebraically closed field of characteristic zero and transcendence basis $(b_\eta)_{\eta<\mathfrak{c}}$, where $\mathfrak{c}$ is the ordinal which happens to be the continuum (in $V$), and even inside $L(\mathbb{R})$ the automorphism group of this field (which happens to be $\cong\mathbb{C}$ in $V$) is very large. But I don't immediately see how to get something between these options, let alone a countably infinite automorphism group.

$L(\Bbb R)$ seems like a very illogical place for such field to exist, if it can exist at all. I don't see why (or why not, though) a field could have countably many automorphisms (other than the finite case).

Perhaps a strategy for a negative answer might be to try and show the automorphism group, if infinite, is perfect in a suitable sense and therefore size at least continuum?

@AsafKaragila I agree, which is why I asked the question - I'm hoping for a negative answer.

@JoelDavidHamkins I thought a bit along those lines but didn't get anywhere. One issue for me is that the doppelganger $F$ might, within $L(\mathbb{R})$, look too large for descriptive set theoretic techniques (at least the ones I'm familiar with) to apply. E.g. if $\vert F\vert^{L(\mathbb{R})}>\Theta$, which I don't immediately see is impossible, I don't see how to do anything useful.

I just meant that if an automorphism (other than conjugation) is nontrivial, then it is moving transcendentals around, but if a sequence of automorphisms are increasingly in agreement on them and their preimages, then the limit will also be automorphism. Can we generate new automorphisms from a given nontrivial automorphism?

@JoelDavidHamkins That's the issue I was getting at with my above comment. I don't see that an $F$ need have a good topology (in $L(\mathbb{R})$) at all, so I don't know how to take limits.

I want just to use the subspace topology inside the symmetries of $F$. That is, view $F$ as discreet, and basic open sets of permutations is determined by finitely much information about how it acts.

@NoahSchweber (1) Within ZF, isomorphic structures have isomorphic automorphism groups, and (2) If f is a continuous automorphism of the complex field, then f is either the identity map or the complex-conjugation map, and (3) In the presence of sufficienly large cardinals, all automorphisms of the complex plane are continuous. Therefore, in L(R) [assuming enough large cardinals], any field isomorphic to the complex field has only two automorphisms. What am I missing?

@NoahSchweber Never mind, I now see that you want F to be isomorphic to the complex field in the real world, not in L(R).

@JoelDavidHamkins Ah, I see. I don't see how to make that work immediately though. For example, it could be (to the best of my knowledge) that $F$ has two nontrivial automorphisms $f,g$ each of finite order such that the sequence $fg,fgfg,fgfgfg,...$ has no limit in that topology.

@NoahSchweber Using indiscernibles, the answer to your question is in the positive if $\aleph_0$ is replaced by $2^{\aleph_0}$. So it appears that the more general open question is obtained by replacing $\aleph_0$ with a cardinal strictly between $2$ and  $2^{\aleph_0}$ in your question.
